# where column in (single value) performance

Tags: t-sql

I am writing dynamic sql code and it would be easier to use a generic `where column in (<comma-seperated values>)` clause, even when the clause might have 1 term (it will never have 0).

So, does this query:

```
select * from table where column in (value1)
```

have any different performance than

```
select * from table where column=value1
```

?

All my test result in the same execution plans, but if there is some knowledge/documentation that sets it to stone, it would be helpful.

Comment: No zero difference. If you look at the query plan generated they will be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not hold true for each and any RDBMS as well as for each an any query with its specific circumstances.

The engine will translate `WHERE id IN(1,2,3)` to `WHERE id=1 OR id=2 OR id=3`.

So your two ways to articulate the predicate will (probably) lead to exactly the same interpretation.

As always: We should not really bother about the way the engine "thinks". This was done pretty well by the developers :-) We tell - through a statement - what we want to get and not **how** we want to get this.

Some more details [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/query-tuning-the-in-clause), especially the first part.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this will depend on platform you are using (optimizer of the given SQL engine).

---

I did a little test using MySQL Server and:

When I query `select * from table where id = 1;` i get 1 total, Query took **0.0043** seconds

When I query `select * from table where id IN (1);` i get 1 total, Query took **0.0039** seconds

I know this depends on Server and PC and what.. But The results are very close.

---

But you have to remember that IN is non-sargable (non search argument able), it will not use the index to resolve the query,  = is sargable and support the index..

---

If you want the best one to use, You should test them in your environment because they both work so good!!

Comment: The *sargability* is broken when using computations on indexed column values, thus breaking the engine's view onto indexed values. But the `IN()`-clause is not non-sargable by itself...